# General ASP.NET Session questions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have some questions in regards to Session in ASP.NET

1. As we need to manually create cookie, does Session automatically created by the application when the application starts?
2. Is it just only one Session object to store all users'information? Or there is new Session object for every user?
3. There is Timeout attribute for Session, can I use this attribute instead of setting expiry time for cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Session Start is its own part of the lifecycle. Each user gets their own session.

Not sure why you would want to link the cookies and sessions in that way. If you just want something alive during the session, just store it in the session.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1
No need to create cookie your own, session id created automatically when you access the url

Question 2
You can create multiple session object to store different data into it and there is new session object for each user because server will auto generate session id for each user access to url

Question 3
Timeout attribute is just to provide an expiry time for the session so the data will not retain in session after a period of time